# Как зашить бинарник в единственный html файл?

Tags: javascript

Делаю кроссбраузерный и кросплатформенный документ, который бы открылся бы везде где есть браузер. Вот только не могу понять, можно ли сделать из него что то вроде ресурса... Я создал переменную js в которую добавил содержимое байтов картинки (получилось на 18000+ строк но не суть). Главное, что переменная не принимает это значение... Возможно нужно кодировку поменять? Или же есть смысл считывать не символы а числа, а уже их засовывать в js и там парсить, получая значение байтов, после чего генерировать картинку? как лучше то?
(https://ibb.co/fSqzNVH)

Comment: Чтобы хранить картинку в виде строки для последующей ее генерации, стоит использовать base64 строку